# How can I do operations in the background when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android-studio, push-notification

I have created a webscraper that gets values from a website.
Now the user can type in a number. There should be a push notification if the value of the website is equal to the user-specific number.
That isn't a problem for itself, but how can I check these values in the background when my app is closed?

I have tried the Alarm-Manager but that didn't help me.
Thanks for your help,

timic

Comment: You'll need to create a service for that: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: Okay thank you. What is the best service in my case?